# Global Variable and operator - between two Global variables

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and programming. I am facing an issue. I have decleared two Global variables here.

```
package com.example.letsbid;

public class GlobalVariable
{
    public static int balance = 100;
    private static int deduction=15;
}
```

Then I assign the value of that Global variable to a text view

```
tv_balance.setText(String.valueOf(GlobalVariable.balance));
```

now I want whenever user click on a specific button that balance should reduce 15 points. for example if it is 100 it should become 85, if its 60 it should become 45.
For that I am trying this

```
         btn_515.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              // error in here following code, i tried balance=balance-15;     
             // I tried balance=balance-deduction;
             // I tried balance==balance+""-deduction+"";
             balance==balance-deduction;

                tv_balance.setText(String.valueOf(GlobalVariable.balance));

                Intent intent = new Intent(BalanceActivity.this, LotteryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But it shows error
operator - cannot be applied to Global variable

Now how can I apply that - to that so that everty time user click on btn_515, 15 should be deducted from his balance.

Comment: Those aren't really "global variables". They're static properties of a class. Also `deduction` is private, so you won't be able to access it either.

Comment: Firstly, `deduction` is private so u can't access it outside class `GlobalVariable` scope, you should read about access modifier. Secondly, `balance==balance-deduction;` just do the comparation and not change the value of `balance`, you should learn how to use operator first.